# How does {all: initial} work? Problem with default values

Tags: html, css, inheritance, line-height

Why does paragraph inherit properties from div such as:
**`line-height`** and **`text-align`**.

If values for these properties are:

1. normal -> for `line-height`

   [i.e. font-size = 16px (initial / default value) * normal (value is
   usually around 1.2 -> 19.2 px)]
2. start -> for `text-align`.

However, the initial values for these properties are overwritten/inherited from the div. Why? I don't understand this. At this point **`all: initial`** behaves like **`all: unset`** with the exception of `font-size`, which is not inherited from div.

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #11a683;
}
p {
  all: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum...
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two slightly different reasons with a common cause.

Setting `all:initial` sets the p element to `display:initial` = `display:inline`.

`text-align` applies to block containers so it has no effect on the now inline p element at all.

`line-height` applies to inline boxes, but the value on the div adds a strut to each line box of 2 x the div's font-size hence spreading the lines out. The "normal" line-height on the p element is substantially less so it has no additional effect.

It's similar in resulting effect to changing the p element to a span element.

Your expected outcome can be achieved by restoring the p element to `display:block`.

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #11a683;
}
p {
  all: initial;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum...
  </p>
</div>
```